# zip does'n show me any issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here i have several images and i need to zip those images and need to download it..In here i use [Ionzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).The problem is that zip is not working.It doen't shows me any error.

MyCode

```
public bool DownloadImgs()
        {  


        string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Content/images/QImages");
        string zippath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Content/images/QImages/zipped/");
        string[] filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);//It returns all the paths of the images.

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (String filename in filenames)
            {
                ZipEntry e = zip.AddFile(filename, "");
            }
            zip.Save(zippath);//In here i need to download the zipped file.not to save
        } 
}
```

PS: This application is built using MVC framework

Comment: so the zip does get created, but you want to download it instead?

Comment: @StevenLemmens No.zip file doesn't created.. But YES i need to download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the resulting zip to the `Response` stream.

From a MVC controller:

```
return this.File(zippath, "application/zip");
```

From an ASP.NET handler or page:

```
Response.TransmitFile(zippath);
```

Another option is to directly save the zip file to the response stream, which will optimize your disk usage.

Comment: there's no response keyword

Comment: Did you use the first line for MVC?

Comment: This is mvc app.In my controller call this function

Comment: Then use the first line as in my answer... And return a `FileResult` instead of a `bool`.

Comment: The problem is here i'm not using ActionResult in here my controller i'm using JsonResult

Comment: Then don't use a `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your zip file straight to the response outputstream:

```
zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: There's no any Response keyword .. Is that HttpResponse ?

Comment: @UDP: That is in ASP.NET Web Forms or HTTP Handlers. For MVC you need something else.

Comment: True. Sorry, I didn't notice he was using MVC

Comment: This is mvc app.In my controller call this function